# Efficient way to perform cell-wise calculation in a large matrix

Tags: r, binary, sapply

I am trying to get 2 bits of 8-bit value from the cloud mask intermediate product of the NASA.

The matrix has a dimension of 3200 x 3248. I have to do this conversion for thousands of data sets.

Here is one of the dataset that I want to do this conversion. [dataset](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jHl4yTmGccHTpPBzIl3zpjB1ZaqHoMr5)

Here is my code:

```
library(binaryLogic)
test = as.logical(c(0,0))
#n_row <- nrow(cmask_1)
n_row <- 100
cmask_2bits  <- matrix(nrow=n_row, ncol=ncol(cmask_1))

t1 <- Sys.time()

for(i in 1:n_row){
  cmask_2bits[i,] <- sapply(cmask_1[i,], function (x) ifelse(identical(as.logical(as.binary(x, n=8)[5:6]), test), 0, 1))
}

t2 <- Sys.time()

time <- difftime(t2, t1)


t1_mthd2 <- Sys.time()

cmask_2bits_mthd2  <- matrix(nrow=n_row, ncol=ncol(cmask_1))

cmask_2bits_mthd2 <- mapply(function (x) 
ifelse(identical(as.logical(as.binary(x, n=8)[5:6]), test), 0, 1), cmask_1[1:n_row,])

cmask_2bits_mthd2 <- matrix(cmask_2bits_mthd2, nrow=n_row, ncol=ncol(cmask_1))

t2_mthd2 <- Sys.time()

time_mthd2 <- difftime(t2_mthd2, t1_mthd2)

time_mthd2 - time
```

I have tried these two lines of code with `mapply` and `sapply` with `for` loop. I am wondering whether `ifelse` statement can be also improved for faster result.

My second question is whether this job (getting thousands of matrices) should be done on Hadoop platform or not.

My result should be like this for the first 10 rows and 10 columns:

[image]

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Edit: As an example, as.binary(15, n=8) gives me the result as 
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 as an 8-bit unsigned character. This binary value is read from the right, so that my 2 bits of interest are 3rd and 4th bits, which are 1 1. Since as.binary(15, n=8) gives me a "binary" "logical" vector, I can get these bits by requesting 5th and 6th values of this code result.

Comment: What is the value of `test`?

Comment: what package is `as.binary` from please

Comment: @W.Murphy edited!

Comment: Not sure if this is right so going to suggest this as a comment in case you wish to explore it.  Your code uses `sapply()`.  The vectorized math in the current answer may be the best approach but just in case, I would try re-writing your code and testing performance on subset 3 ways - the two given plus a version using `map()`.  If you can rewrite it that way you might see an unexpected boost.  There seem to be different use cases where different approaches work faster than others.  `map()` would require mapping a function over your matrix if that works.

Answer (score 1):

For the broader question, the most efficient method for cell-wise operations on a large matrix, when the operation is identical for every cell, is to use the built-in vectorized operations. A matrix in R is really just a vector with some metadata about dimensions. For your specific question, in addition to vectorization, it looks like that `binaryLogic.asBinary` is not computationally efficient. For your simple case of bits 5 and 6 being zero in an 8 bit integer, just do it with integer math:

```
(((cmask_1 %% 128) %% 64) < 16) + 0
```

The modulos clear out bits 7 and 8, and from there all values with bits 5 and 6 equal to zero will be less than 16. Adding 0 to the result converts from a logical vector to 0/1.

Edit: looking back at your example it looks like you want the result to be zero when bits 5 and 6 are both zero. That would be:

```
(((cmask_1 %% 128) %% 64) > 15) + 0
```

Comment: Thank you for this code. It gives the result very fast. But I have just edited my question that the first 10 x 10 matrix observations should be the same as in the image. I checked these bits from the HDFView software as well that these conversion is the correct one. But the code gave me different.

Comment: Your suggestion is simple, but needs to be fixed. I edited the question that my 2 bits of interest are the 3rd and 4th bits, i.e., values for 2^3 and 2^2. In this case, I can follow your code to write down ((((((((3 %% 256) %% 128) %% 64) %% 32) %% 16) %% 8) %% 4) > 2) + 0

Comment: however, it is not clear whether the number from the cmask_1 is divided by 8 and 4 or not.  As an example, both 15 and 3 have a remainder of 3 after the division of 4. But 3 is not divided by 8 and 4, while 15 was divided by 8 and 4. In this case, 3 should be recoded 0, while 15 is 1.

Comment: @Mustafa thanks for the clarification; I was wondering if I had the bit order backwards. It might be possible to simplify the answer you added, but there's one thing I'm still unsure on: for what values in those two bits should be output be zero versus one?

Comment: The documentation of this data product says that the 2 bits of my interest represent the value for cloud mask: confidently clear, clear, cloudy, and confidently cloudy. Since 2 bits refers to the values of 00, 01, 10, and 11, if I am not wrong. Then, my aim is to get that cloud mask for "confidently clear" elements, so that I would like to get 00 from the 2 bits of my interest. Here is the link to the documentation (page 10). https://jointmission.gsfc.nasa.gov/sciencedocs/2015-06/474-00001-04-01_JPSS-CDFCB-X-Vol-IV-Part-1_0124A.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I think the fastest method is to use bitwise logical operators. If you want to extract bit 3 and 4 from an integer X you can use "X AND 12" (4 + 8 = 12). As result you get "4" if the 3rd bit is set, "8" for the 4th bit and "12" if the 3rd and 4th bit are set.

In R there is the package "bitops" which support the operations you need:

```
library(bitops)
mat_cmask = as.matrix(df_cmask)
v = as.vector(mat_cmask, mode="integer")
v1 = bitAnd(v, 12) # there are still values 4, 8 and 12
v2 = as.integer(v1>0)
result = matrix(v2, nrow=nrow(cmask), ncol(cmask)) 
result[1:10, 1:10]
```

Best, Stefan

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @W. Murphy for this simple and clear answer. The correct answer following integer division should be

(((((((cmask_1 %% 256) %% 128) %% 64) %% 32) %% 16) < 16) & (3 < (((((cmask_1 %% 256) %% 128) %% 64) %% 32) %% 16))) + 0,

where I wanted to restrict the remainder between 3 and 16, so that the number will fall in this interval will be divided by either 8 or 4 or both.

Thanks again.